# performing segue from GameScene to a Main Menu

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, segue

Hello I am trying to perform a segue when a label is clicked from the game in `GameScene` back to the `mainMenu`, the `MainMenu` is created in storyboard and there is a segue set up from the `GameScene` to the `MainMenu` named `gameToMain`. The code that I currently have to accomplish this is:

In the GameSceneViewController my code is

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size))

    scene.viewController = self
}
```

and in my GameScene I added

```
var viewController: UIViewController?
```

and

```
func segue(){  
  self.viewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameToMain", sender: viewController)    
}
```

I get the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil` while unwrapping an Optional value.

I believe the problem is the sender and I have set up a `mainMenuViewController` but I am not sure how to fix the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Is your `GameScene` in a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: no it is not @AdrianB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are not setting `viewController` because you are getting this as an error...

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil`

When you create your `GameScene` I am guessing you are not setting the viewController variable correctly. It is hard to know for sure with the limited code you provided, but I would look there first. If it isn't the issue I would update your question on how you create gameScene and when.

You could also log out the view controller before you call the segue just to verify it is or is not nil.

**Edit**

After getting the additional code I believe your issue is here...

```
skView.presentScene(GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size))
```

You are creating a completely new scene and not using the scene you created above. It should be this...

```
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Also if you want to go back to the previous viewController you wouldn't call a segue in this example it would be something like this..

```
viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: how exactly would I go about this?

Comment: Which part? Logging out the view controller to make sure it isn't nil or showing all the code of where you create the scene?

Comment: logging out the view controller. I assume you mean by using // but how would I do that without getting the error "use of unresolved identifier 'viewController'".  Also my gameScene is created when a button is pressed in the mainMenu (created in storyboard) and I am trying to segue back to that same mainMenu

Comment: @Kevin you should be able to do println(viewController) before you call performSegueWithIdentifer. Also update your question with all the code from that button press. You don't actually need to segue if you are going back. That is typically a pop or dismiss. If you post the code from the button press that creates gameScene I should be able to help from there.

Comment: The viewController is indeed nil.  The button press that creates GameScene is created in storyboard by adding a button and control dragging from that button to the gameScene so there is no available code.

Comment: @Kevin that means I need to see the code in view did load on gameViewController where you creat the gameScene.

Comment: @Kevin I updated my answer. I think I know what the issue is now =)

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you so much I have had this problem for a few weeks now :)

Comment: @Kevin No problem and glad I was able to help. Good luck on your game.

Comment: I have been using this method but every so often viewController will be nil and the app will crash